# How to install artifact using maven-antrun-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-ant-tasks

I have a project that some ant files target to extract different packages (I'm the guy who comes and see this ugliness, not the one who did it).

So, one package, one ant, one jar.

And different OTHERS projects use one or more of this jars.

I can't touch the folder structure.

I have to migrate this (and the other projects) to maven, but other than make several poms that exclude all others packages and compile it's own, I don't know how to solve this problem.

I'm not very good with ant, but I read [here](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html) that ant-task can install into the local repository, so it can make easy for the dependent projects to use those jars.

Can anyone can help me with an example of how to use the ant-task-plugin to achive this, or a better approach?

Comment: Have you tried installing jars to your local repository? Try this.                      [ mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Fully Qualified Jar location} -DgroupId=your.group.Id -DartifactId=your.artifact.id -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar ] As you have jars created by Ant, you will need to assign your artifactid and groupId. And then reuse there jars in other apps. This will be quick for you.

Comment: @asg Thanks for the suggestion, but it has to be build in several enviroments, so a local install was not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do and work for me was to add a new maven-jar project and change the source folder so it points to the mentioned folder.
Then I exclude the packages so it can generate the required jar.
Repeat for every jar I have to make this way.

Add this projects to the parent pom, so the can be created at once with the dependent projects.

Hope this help someone.